# why currying does not work with a function literal?

Tags: scala, function, currying

What is the logical reason that the first form works and not the second?

```
scala> val d = (a: Int, b: Int) => a + b
d: (Int, Int) => Int = <function2>

scala> val d = (a: Int)(b: Int) => a + b

<console>:1: error: not a legal formal parameter.
Note: Tuples cannot be directly destructured in method or function parameters.
 Either create a single parameter accepting the Tuple1,
 or consider a pattern matching anonymous function: `{ case (param1, param1) => ... }
 val d=(a:Int)(b:Int)=>a+b
```

Comment: `val d = (a:Int) => (b:Int) => a+b`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because multiple parameter lists aren't allowed on function declarations. If you want to curry a function, you do:

```
scala> val d: Int => Int => Int  = a => b => a + b
d: Int => (Int => Int) = $$Lambda$1106/512934838@6ef4cbe1

scala> val f = d(3)
f: Int => Int = $$Lambda$1109/1933965693@7e2c6702

scala> f(4)
res6: Int = 7
```

You can also create a single parameter list and partially apply it:

```
scala> val d = (a: Int, b: Int) => a + b
d: (Int, Int) => Int = $$Lambda$1064/586164630@7c8874ef

scala> d(4, _: Int)
res2: Int => Int = $$Lambda$1079/2135563436@4a1a412e
```

We partially applied `d`  with 4, and we got back a function, `Int => Int`, which means when we supply the next argument, we'll get the result:

```
scala> res2(3)
res3: Int = 7
```

We can also create a named method, and use eta-expansion to create a curried function out of it:

```
scala> def add(i: Int)(j: Int): Int = i + j
add: (i: Int)(j: Int)Int

scala> val curriedAdd = add _
curriedAdd: Int => (Int => Int) = $$Lambda$1115/287609100@f849027

scala> val onlyOneArgumentLeft = curriedAdd(1)
onlyOneArgumentLeft: Int => Int = $$Lambda$1116/1700143613@77e9dca8

scala> onlyOneArgumentLeft(2)
res8: Int = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Function currying is possible.

```
val curryFunc = (a: Int) => (b: Int) => a + b
```

curryFunc now has the type `Int => (Int => Int)`